# How can I capture frames?

Tags: c#, video, windows-runtime

How can I capture frame from webcam? I know about `GetPreviewFrameAsync` and `CapturePhotoTo...()` But may be is there another way?
And how can I capture audio frames? Now I capture frames from the stream:

```
    private async Task GetBytesFromAudioStream()
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = new DataReader(Audiostream.GetInputStreamAt(FirstAudPos));
            _audioBytes = null;
            _audioBytes = new byte[this.Audiostream.Size - FirstAudPos];
            //Bytes.Text = FirstAudPos + " - " + Audiostream.Size + " = " + (Audiostream.Size - FirstAudPos);
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)(Audiostream.Size - FirstAudPos));
            reader.ReadBytes(_audioBytes);
            FirstAudPos = Audiostream.Size;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser(ex.ToString()+ " GetBytesFromAudioStream");
        }
    }
```

But this way isn't good. I know about AudioGraph but I don't know how I can convert float to PCM.
So can somebody help me?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I have here a piece of code where I take a picture from a webcam. Actually it prints the current webcam screen.  Wanna take a look?

Comment: @Forlani Of course I want to see your code. If you can show.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna share my code with you , are you using MVVM? I can set up a small project to you

Comment: No, I don't use MVVM. You can say me about your method and you won't show code.

Comment: @Forlani Do you know how I can read byte array from InMemoryRandomAccessStream and delete this array from this stream?